# Combining multiple columns into a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, unpivot, normalize

Using Excel, how can I create a single column using multiple columns?

For example: I might need to eliminate columns 2012-2014 and create a column for year. At the same time, I need to keep the information in 2012-2014 and create a single column for these to align to each row (Name, Country, Grade, Year, data):

```
Name        Country   Grade 2012        2013        2014
Smith       France    A     0.333194233 0.64347979  0.72795544
Adams       Germany   D     0.307532421 0.580823282 0.851274645
Franklin    Americas  C     4.597219783 7.983514354 10.79688839
Roosevelt   Americas  B     0.615064841 1.089043653 1.502249374
Washington  Australia A     0.261792462 0.456573955 0.620206846
```

So it should look like this:

```
Name        Country   Grade Year Data
Smith       France    A     2012 0.333194233
Smith       France    A     2013 0.64347979
Smith       France    A     2014 0.72795544 etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Name` is in A1, insert a new ColumnD and in D1 copied down to suit:

```
=A1&"#"&B1&C1
```

then unpivot (details with images [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) selecting D1:Gn (`n` to suit)).

After step 8. insert three new columns in the Table (to become B:D) and in B2:

```
 =LEFT(A2,FIND("#",A2)-1)
```

in C2:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("#",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)-2)
```

in D2:

```
=RIGHT(A2)
```

Tidy up to suit.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried TRANSPOSE in 'Paste Special'? or do you want it dynamic?

[Link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2)

Found solution in: [LINK](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/532957-transpose-rowsg-keeping-heading-column-data-column-b.html) It works!

Create this module and run the Macro:

```vb
Public Sub tranpose()
Dim i   As Long, _
    LR1 As Long, _
    LR2 As Long, _
    LC  As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
LR2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Range("A1:A" & LR2).Value = Chr(65)
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 3 To LC
    LR1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    LR2 = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).row
    Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LR2, i)).Cut Destination:=Cells(LR1, 2)
    Range(Cells(LR1, 1), Cells(LR1 + LR2 - 1, 1)).Value = Chr(63 + i)
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The TRANSPOSE function returns a vertical range of cells as a horizontal range, or vice versa. I need to create more rows of information. As you can see, there is only one row with "Smith" and his information. I need three rows of Smith, same information, however with additional columns, years and data. This needs to be done for about 3000 rows of information.

Comment: [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/532957-transpose-rowsg-keeping-heading-column-data-column-b.html)